# Reactjs Typescript contact parameter problem

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

```
const ValidateLogin = (contact) => {
    let errors = {};
    if (!contact.email) {
    } else if (!/\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test(contact.email)) {
        errors.email = "Email address is invalid";
    }
    if (!contact.password) {
        errors.password = "Password is required";
    } else if (contact.password.length < 10) {
        errors.password = "Password needs to be more than 10 characters";
    }
    return errors;
}

export default ValidateLogin
```

i am getting error on `(contact)`: Parameter 'contact' implicitly has an 'any' type.
and on email and password: Property 'email' does not exist on type '{}'.

Comment: Yes, you don't specify the type of either `contact` or `errors`. Did you consider... specifying those types? Maybe start with https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html.

Comment: Thank you i am beginner... do you mean as interface?

Comment: Yes, you could use an interface.

Comment: And contact should be defined as what type?

Comment: We can't tell you that. What *are* you intending to pass in? Something with optional string `email` and `password` properties, at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define an interface or type alias for contact, with required properties. This is how you can do it:

```
interface Contact {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  // include other required properties
}

type Error = Partial<Contact>;

const ValidateLogin = (contact: Contact) => {
  let errors: Error = {};
  // rest of the code
};
```

Comment: this has resolved the contact problem, but email and password error is still there

Comment: @JosipMarić that is because we need to define the typings for the `errors` variable as well. I have updated my code.

Comment: now i get in ```let errors: Error = {};```:Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Contact': email, password

Comment: @JosipMarić oh, my bad. should make set it Partial too. Now it should work